# Backing out bad PR merge on GitHub

Tags: git, github, revert

I've got a GitHub repo that *loosely* follows git-flow. There are two long-standing branches: `master` and `develop`. Two feature branches (`feature/one` and `feature/two`) that were cut off of `develop` some time ago. PRs were created for both of these two merge back into `develop`.

The `feature/one` PR had junk code it in, but I accidentally merged it into `develop` and want to back it out. What are the specific commands I can use to "undo" this "junk PR" merge? Is it possible to do this all from inside of GitHub, or do I have to make the revert locally and then push it to GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `git revert` here, as you would for a non merge commit, but you'll have to also specify which parent you want to follow:

```
git revert <SHA-1 of merge commit> -m 1
```

This will add a new commit which will functionally undo the merge commit and bring the branch back to the first parent.  If you wanted the second parent, you would use `-m 2`.

There probably is a way to directly handle this from the GitHub UI, but it can also be handled locally.

Comment: Thanks @Tim (+1) - so I can easily find the SHA-1 commit of the merge, but am not 100% seeing the "forest through the trees" on the parent/`m`-arg side. I just want to undo the `develop` branch and restore it to the state it was in prior to the merge. It sounds like you're saying `-m 1` is the appropriate command then? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb [This post](https://www.christianengvall.se/undo-pushed-merge-git/) and my recollection say that the first parent is the target of the merge and the second parent is what you merged into the target.  But you can try `-m 1` and just check afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Tim (+1) last question (I promise!). I assume I have to commit + push the revert after I make it? Or maybe just push?

Comment: I think the revert will add the commit automatically, so you should just need to push.  And ideally there won't be any conflicts forcing you to pull first.